# SEO impact (on rankings) for a global website with a physical address

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results

Assume I have a website that displays a London physical address on the footer, about-us and contact us pages. However, the website carries country neutral content that I would want to rank well across countries starting from the US in the west to Russia in the east.

The site uses ".com" , a generic TLD.

In such a case can the physical address hurt the rankings in countries other than the UK?

Comment: Also, I would like to mention that the site uses ".com" , a generic TLD.

Comment: ***In such a case can the physical address hurt the rankings in countries other than the UK?*** It should not.

Answer (score 2):

A business website having or not having a physical address doesn't normally impact a site's ranking *directly*, however, it can influence the rankings indirectly. Instead of it being considered a direct SEO ranking factor, it's more considered an ingredient in the trust recipe between the website and Google (and other major Search Engines). Having the address in the footer match the address on the contact page, the about us page helps establish congruency. Plus if the business is also listed in Google Business, Facebook, shows up on Google Maps, etc. this further deepens that trust factor, which can then, in turn, help a site's rankings.

Furthermore, If people are searching for the business address, phone number, etc in Google, then having the address easily found on the website - by both users and search spiders - will only have a positive impact. The location of the user in relation to the business itself shouldn't negate this.

All in all, it comes down to the primary mantra and core value of Google on putting the (human) user first. If the address in the footer solves a user's query better, faster, more efficiently etc. chances are it'll help you with Google and other search engines, and very, very rarely would it ever harm your sites rankings.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a little of my thoughts to the excellent answer Joseph B.
By default, the information about the website publisher set in the footer. If the information has confirmation, for example, with a link that is connected with the Google knowledge panel for organizing the publisher, then this is a signal for a high level of trustworthiness, as the Google tells us in the recommendations ***Expertise, Authoritativeness, Trustworthiness - EAT***:

> ● Who (what individual, company, business, foundation, etc.) is
>   responsible for the website.
>
> ● Who (what individual, company,
>   business, foundation, etc.) created the content on the page.

Google repeats roughly the same in its **[What webmasters should know about Google’s core updates](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/08/core-updates.html)**:

> Expertise questions
>
> Does the content present information in a way that
>   makes you want to trust it, such as clear sourcing, evidence of the
>   expertise involved, background about the author or the site that
>   publishes it, such as through links to an author page or a site’s
>   About page?

In addition, an indication of the established and verified publisher is a **[Google requirement for publishers of news websites](https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/answer/6204050)**:

> Transparency
>
> Visitors to your site want to trust and understand who
>   publishes it and information about those who have written articles.
>   That's why news sources on Google should provide clear dates, bylines,
>   information about authors, the publication, the publisher, company or
>   network behind it, and contact information.

***Therefore, my answer to your question***: an indication of a valid and verified publisher is a positive signal that indicates a high level of trustworthiness of the content of the website.

Comment: I understand a physical address can enhance trust in the eyes of both visitors and Google. But my question was specifically about the relative ranking in different geo-locations depending upon the physical address.

Comment: In my humble opinion, such a relationship does not exist. In the end, the web network has global reach.